# What does 一般 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

'一般' 的意思? 初学者的问题 我查了字典这个词的意思，但我不明白

这个词
经常看到
我想知道意思
一般来说

i guess in English nuances is close to
generally
rule of thumb
broadly speaking

p.s. I am quarter British so idk wide knowledge of hanzi

Answer (score 1):

Some meanings of 一般：

他们俩一般高。
They are both the same height.

别有一般滋味。
(It) has a distinctive flavour.

一般常识
common sense
一般常识、讲故事的能力和熟练计算的能力也很有帮助。
Common sense, storytelling ability and being skilled at calculating are all very helpful.

一般情况
normal/ordinary circumstances
一般情况下，我会说“行”。
Under normal circumstances, I would say yes.

I agree with r13: 一般来说的“一般”：generally/broadly speaking

Comment: 别有一般滋味 should be 别有一番滋味 (There is a special feeling in me which is so different and hard to describe.

Answer (score 1):

translation: normal(ly), common(ly), most of the time

some synonyms: 通常，普遍

Answer (score 0):

一般来(commonly/generally)说(speaking), also "broadly speaking". Note, 一般来说 = 一般地说, 来 serves the same as 地.

Answer (score 0):

It can also have a meaning of so-so. Not great, but not terrible. I've heard it used saying things like food or a movie are "一般般"